# Error with createStatement using SQL - JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

First of all, im from Uruguay, my mother tongue is spanish so sorry for my english :)

The problem is this: [image: Here is the problem in an image]

Hello, im new using SQL in Java. I have a problem trying to execute a query, the problem is that i found how to connect to the data base, that's ok, but when I try to do a query outside of the connection class I get an error...

```
Statement query = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = query.executeQuery("SELECT Nombre FROM Usuarios WHERE Tele = 2001");
```

Here "connection" is with error

This is how im connecting to the database (This is in public void main):

```
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("¿Dónde está el driver?");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Driver encontrado");
        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java_project","root", "usbw");
            System.out.println("Variable 'connection' = " + connection);


        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("La conexión falló, mire los errores en consola.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("Conexión a la base de datos establecida");
        } else {
            System.out.println("La conexión falló");
        }
```

Probably this is easy for you but I try a lot of things and i don't get it. I will be glad if someone can help me, thanks for your time, Gonzalo.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help] and read [ask].  You have to provide the complete stack trace, with all "caused by" sections, and identify the line in your code that caused the exception.  [edit] your post and add the stack trace, formatted as code.

Comment: can you say columns data types?

Comment: What is the error you got?

Comment: Check with this way: ResultSet rs = query.executeQuery("SELECT Nombre FROM Usuarios WHERE Tele='2001' ");

Answer (score 0):

According your screenshot you have not define connection. Pls arrange code this way. Also do not use many try catch blocks. Use code as follows. Also 
remove com.mysql.jdbc.* and use import java.sql.*. Also according to your code you have not pass connection as a parameter in proper way.
Here I changed your code: http://pastebin.com/6wftE9tp

```
Connection connection = null;
           Statement query = null;
           try{
              //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
              Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

              //STEP 3: Open a connection
              System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
              connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java_project","root", "usbw");
              System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

              //STEP 4: Execute a query
              System.out.println("Creating statement...");
              query = connection.createStatement();


              ResultSet rs = query.executeQuery("SELECT Nombre FROM Usuarios WHERE Tele = 2001");
              //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
              while(rs.next()){
                 //Retrieve data

              }
              rs.close();
           }catch(SQLException se){
              //Handle errors for JDBC
              se.printStackTrace();
           }catch(Exception e){
              //Handle errors for Class.forName
              e.printStackTrace();
           }finally{
              //finally block used to close resources
              try{
                 if(query!=null)
                     connection.close();
              }catch(SQLException se){
              }// do nothing
              try{
                 if(connection!=null)
                     connection.close();
              }catch(SQLException se){
                 se.printStackTrace();
              }//end finally try
           }//end try
```

Pls refer this : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-select-records.htm

Comment: It give this error on connection.CreateStatement();

"Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.sql.Statement to com.mysql.jdbc.Statement"


Im trying to execute a query outside the main class, im using it when i click a button, is that possible?

Thank you for your answer

Comment: Remove com.mysql.jdbc.Statement. Use import java.sql.Connection. Yes. You can run your query as you wish.

Comment: Check the answer with image below, still the same :'(

Comment: Pls add complete class as image without partially.

Comment: This is all the class http://pastebin.com/UiQRMiyR    Im trying to do a register/login, thanks for your time!

Comment: pls replace this line  import com.mysql.jdbc.*  with java.sql.* Use all things in java.sql.*

Comment: Here I changed your code: http://pastebin.com/6wftE9tp. Now no error. Pls refer this code. you will be understand what is the problem. Pls mark this answer is correct if you satisfy with this answer.